# Lifetime mismatch with self referencing structs in a `Vec`

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have the following code which you can also see in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=768b3ad14033fadc27e6ae0bb1e75e0f):

```
struct Node<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
    name: &'a str,
}

fn looper(nodes: &mut Vec<Node>) {
    for i in 0..nodes.len() {
        let n = &nodes[i];
        let next_node = Node {
            parent: Some(n),
            name: "please compile",
        };
        nodes.push(next_node);
    }
}
```

It's supposed to take a `Vec` of `Node`s and append `Node`s to it that reference the `Node`s already in the `Vec`. Unfortunately I get this error:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/main.rs:13:20
   |
6  | fn looper(nodes: &mut Vec<Node>) {
   |                  -------------- these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
...
13 |         nodes.push(next_node);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `nodes` flows into `nodes` here
```

How can I make this compile? An explanation of how to think about lifetimes in this context would be useful. I understand this may be an issue due to [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance) but am not sure how to rephrase my problem to give me the functionality I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general rule: when some value's type, or trait it implements, has a lifetime parameter, that lifetime is always *longer* than the life of the value itself — the value has a guarantee that the references it contains won't go invalid before they are dropped.

In fact, in your example we can see that if this were not the case, the lifetime checking would be unsound; you're *adding* values to `nodes`, but nothing would prevent `looper` from instead *removing* values from `nodes`, which would then invalidate any `parent` references that referred to those values.

The only practical way to build a tree or linked list *of references* (without special-purpose unsafe code that has a particular plan to keep things sound) is to write a recursive function; each function call frame may refer to nodes constructed *by its caller* (and its caller's caller and so on). This is accepted by the borrow checker because each frame has its own new, **shorter** lifetime for the references (a reference can always be taken as having a shorter lifetime than it started with).

Comment: Even _adding_ values is unsound, because adding values to a vec may cause the vec to be reallocated, thus invalidating all existing references.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I understand now why I am way off base with my code.